# embed multiple view controller in one window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cohesion

I want to have a View which contains more than one view. see the below image:
[image]

as you see pageController controls page navigation and provide before and after viewController (page).

pageContentController displays text and process them.

soundPlayer manages playing related sound

I can have all of them in one controller, but my controller must do a lot of tasks and managing it will be hard task. as it disobey light view controller. and decrease its cohesion.
so I wanted to know how can I accomplish this
please explain in details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks for your detailed answers. your answers clarified me. what I did:

I added `SoundPalyerVC` as child of `PageContentVC`

```
SoundPlayerVC *soundPlayer = [[StoryViewController alloc] initWithStory:self.storyManagedObject];
[self addChildViewController:soundPlayer];
[self.view addSubview:soundPlayer.view];
[soundPlayer didMoveToParentViewController:self];
soundPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-soundPlayer.view.frame.size.height, 320, soundPlayer.view.frame.size.height);
```

that was so easy. now my codes are separated.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

1) Create custom classes for each view.
2) Then I would set the View Classes to the classes that I created.

[image: Setting the Class of the View to the custom created class]

3) Then I would write the code to handle whatever functionality you need within these view classes.

```
@interface PageContent : UIView

- (void) showTest : (NSString *) textToShow;

@end

@implementation PageContent 

- (void) showTest : (NSString *) textToShow
{
    //Then here you would do whatever you need to do with this text, and display it
}
@end

@interface SoundPlayer : UIView

- (void) playSound;

@end


@implementation SoundPlayer

-(void) playSound
{
    //Do whatever you need to do with the sound here.
}

@end
```

4) Then create outlets to each one of these views in your View Controller Class.

```
//So your View Controller Class would look something like this.

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Page *page;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PageContent *pageContent;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SoundPlayer *soundPlayer;

@end
```

5) Then in your View Controller @implementation you could do stuff like

```
@implementation YourViewController

-(void) showContent
{
    [self.pageContent showText:@"Text To Show"];
}
-(void) playSound
{
    [self.soundPlayer playSound];
}

@end
```

Now when you call these ([self showContent] or [self playSound]) methods in the view controller, it will call the methods for the specific views, so that way you don't have an extremely long non reusable view controller.

I just showed a view examples, I hope that you can see what I'm doing here, and implement this for everything that you need.

Answer (score 1):

To your pageController view, add pageContentController's view and soundPlayer's view as subview to it.

write below code in pageController.m file

```
soundPlayer = [[SoundPlayer alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:soundPlayer.view];
souldPlayer.frame = //set it value as desired.
```

Similary the pageContentController.

Comment: No, you'r not supposed to do that. The only way you're supposed to mix views from different view controllers is using the parent/child view controller methods added in iOS 5 and expanded in iOS 6 (see my post below). I've tried what you describe and it causes all sorts of problems, especially with auto-rotation and forwarding of system notifications like low memory notifications, shake events, etc, etc. It IS possible, but Apple says not to do it, and the burden is on you to get everything working correctly. Why fight it? Embed segues make it SOOO easy!

Answer (score 1):

Starting in iOS 5, Apple added parent/child view controller support to the OS. There are new calls in the UIViewController class to support setting up parent/child view controller relationships, where one view controller (the parent) sets up or ore more other view controllers so that their content views are inserted into the view hierarchy of the parent. This was a major improvement, but a fair amount of work to set up correctly and make everything work right.

Starting in iOS 6, Apple added container views (which is just a UIView with a special type) and embed segues. What you do is open up the scene of the view controller that's going to be the parent in IB, select the list of interface objects, and type "container". You should see a container view. Drag a container view onto your parent view controller and place it where you want it.

Then control-drag from your container view to the scene that defines the interface of the child view controller you want to place in that container. It should default to creating an embed segue. Accept the default. That's pretty much it. Now, when you load the parent view controller, the system will also instantiate any child view controllers that you have set up and wire up all the "plumbing" that makes it work correctly.

If you need the parent and child to communicate you can set an identifier on your embed segue and then write prepareForSegue code that configures the child, just like any other segue.

Container views and embed segues are WONDERFUL, and make setting up this sort of thing really easy.

I have a sample project on github that uses embed segues to good effect. Here's the link:

[**Demo project using embed segues to manage 2 static table views in a parent VC.**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test)

Answer (score 0):

i would realize that with the container view object via interface builder. from the description:
"Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller. Create an embed segue from the container view to the child view controller in the storyboard."

This way you would define exact the two regions you want as child viewcontroller in your parent viewcontroller and you could load in your pageContent a UIPageViewController and in your soundplayer your playercontroller.